# iphone multithread api

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading

I have a problem with the Objective c mutithreaded method.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayThread2Counts:)
      withObject:myNumber
      waitUntilDone:NO];
```

What is the meaning of the parameter "waitUntilDone"?

What is the difference between `waitUntilDone:YES` and `waitUntilDone:NO`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is pretty transparent:

> A Boolean that specifies whether the
>   current thread blocks until after the
>   specified selector is performed on the
>   receiver on the main thread. Specify
>   YES to block this thread; otherwise,
>   specify NO to have this method return
>   immediately.

In other words, if you specify YES for the waitUntilDone parameter no other action will take place on the current thread until the requested selector has finished its work.

However as a corollary, if you're only using a single thread (the main thread) there's no value in specifying YES, as all you're effectively doing is calling the requested selector as you would in a non-threaded environment.

Comment: Yeah,Tank you middaparka!Just now I wrote a demo,and it proved what you said is right.The documentation is pretty transparent,English is not my mother language so I have a little difficulty to understand it,your answer is more transparent than the document!Thanks again